# Upgrade vCenter 5.1 to 5.5 error 29102

Tags: vmware-vcenter, single-sign-on, upgrade

I'm upgrading vCenter 5.1 to 5.5.  After successful upgrading of `Single Sign-On` service, in the next step of upgrading `Web Client` when it needs Single Sign-On password and `Lookup Service Url` it used my last computer name as the default.  When I set a new computer name or last computer name it gave the error number 29102 which says "Unable to contact Lookup Service.."

How can I solve it?

Comment: So is the SSO running on that computer?  What do you mean by "last computer name" - is the upgrade happening on a new system or the existing one?

Answer (score 1):

I came across this question having stumbled upon the same issue myself. The resolution for me was to use an account where the username didn't have any special characters in it. We had an exclamation mark in the username.

We created a new account and the whole installation completed without any further issues.

Neil